# cannot forward from wlan interface to another wlan interface

Tags: networking, wifi, iptables, hotspot

I have two wlan interfaces: `wlan0` `wlan1`.

`wlan0` is an AP managed by hostapd, where as `wlan1` is a normal wifi interface, which is connected to my home router via wpa_supplicant.
Additionally I have my `eth0` interface, which is also connected to my router. I want to build up a wifi repeater for the pi.

I have the following iptables rules

```
AP_INTERFACE="wlan0" # ap
SOURCE_INTERFACE="wlan1" # to router

# Flush rules
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F

# Apply new rules
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $SOURCE_INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $SOURCE_INTERFACE -o $AP_INTERFACE -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $AP_INTERFACE -j ACCEPT

# Save rules
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 # iptables-persistent
```

If I use this script to set my iptables rules, the clients connected to the AP cannot access anything else than the Pi itself, because the packets are not forwarded. If I changed the `SORUCE_INTERFACE` to `eth0` it works for unknown reasons.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 10.10.11.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan1
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan1
10.10.11.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: This may be the default route.
Run `route -n` to display the routing table.

Comment: I added the route -n output to the post.

Comment: So you have two default routes to Internet (0.0.0.0) but eth0 has priority, having the lowest metric. At this point you could try: `(sudo) route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 10.10.10.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0` and test again. NB: untested but should work.

Comment: That actually fixed it! Can I instead of deleting just change the priority of the route? Changing the priority would be the solution. (Edit your answer)

Comment: I see several options from now: one option would be to set fixed metrics in your interfaces file (see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292940/how-to-set-a-routing-table-that-prefers-wlan-dhcp-interface-as-default-route. Another option would be tweaking your DHCP settings to discard that secondary route on eth0 (See: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=90469)

Comment: My solution is now, to dynamically switch between eth0 and wlan1, by getting the Interface with the highest priority and always running my script if any interface gets up or down